# How can I download videos from MegaVideo?

Tags: video, software-rec

How can I download videos from [MegaVideo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megaupload)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Mac users, discover the hidden powers of Safari. In the activity index, you can grab almost any item that is embedded in flash, and save it to disk.

Answer (score 6):

Download MegaVideo videos with [Megavideo Video Downloader](http://www.downloadtoolz.com/megavideo/).

[image]

**(or)**

Go to [cinemaf.com](http://cinemaf.com). It is very important to note that this online service works only with Internet Explorer.

**(or)**

However with this little trick bought to you by [HelloGiri](http://www.hellogiri.com/download-video-from-megavideo-site-and-forget-youtube/) you can easily download and save MegaVideo videos to your computer and watch them offline whenever you like.

1. Open your MegaVideo video in your browser and let it load fully
2. After you are done watching the video online, go to Tools -> Internet Options -> Settings -> View Files (For Internet Explorer)
3. Now you will get a large size file with long name and unknown type there
4. Copy and paste that file at the desktop. This file is the video file in Flash video format (.flv)
5. Rename it with the `flv` extension, for example, `MyMega.flv`.
   [(source)](http://www.sizlopedia.com/2007/08/29/download-megavideo-video/)

**(or)**

Install the popular Firefox extension called [Downloadhelper](http://www.downloadhelper.net/). It is able to download any streaming content running in your Firefox browser, so you can easily download videos from ANY video streaming sites with a single click.

**(or)**

Using [Internet Download Manager](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/download.html) (IDM). In the newer versions of IDM, support for downloading streaming Flash video files has been added which means you can download videos from all of your favorite streaming websites.

[image]

Comment: Megavideo Downloader UI is.. like.. YEAH!!!

Answer (score 4):

[Mega Video Downloader](http://download.cnet.com/Mega-Video-Downloader-FLV-CAP/3000-2648_4-10792526.html).  'Nuff said.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead [Clip Nabber](http://clipnabber.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the URL from `megavideo.com/{etc}` to `megaupload.com/{etc}`. You don't need any software, but you can't download files over 1 GB.